# Wordpress Elementor - Lightbox Issue + Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox, elementor

I have a unpleasant situation. I use Elementor Plugin on my wordpress site.

The theme was made with Jquery version v3.2.1. All actions are related to this version. So, I include this in footer.

So.. I did not known that wordpress use his own Jquery that's loaded from wp-includes. There's version 1.12.4. It's included in header.

Problem is in compatibility with elementor galery lightbox. You can see it here: https://selectrent.md/catalog/mobila/. In Chrome, the lightbox doesn't working. I mean the arrows. I tested in Firefox and Chrome mobile - all it's ok. But on Chrome Desktop doesn't working.

If I remove my Jquery, lightbox works. But all my actions doesn't.

So.. can you provide me a solution to solve this problem without remade my theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using premium plugin, did you try to contact their support?

Comment: @Janis No, I use the free version of plugin.

Comment: @Janis Sure.. I try to contact them but unsuccessful at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a temporary solution. I just deregister my jquery on the pages with lightboxes. I’m lucky there’s no need for that.

Here's issue log: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/lightbox-issue-jquery-conflict/

Thanks!